# How do I detect whether the CPU has good POPCNT support?

Tags: performance, rust, cpu

I have two versions of a [fast newline-counting routine](https://github.com/llogiq/newlinebench).  One runs on older hardware, while the other one runs much faster by using the POPCNT instruction, which is available on newer hardware (e.g. 6th generation Intel CPUs).

Now I'd like to use the best version for each CPU — how can I find out if it has a high-performance POPCNT implementation?

Comment: Shouldn't [`count_ones`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.count_ones) do that automatically?

Comment: @starblue it can be different. Using `count_ones` will allow LLVM to optimize for the **target** machine, so you could remove any runtime decisions. If the compiled code needs to be able to switch at runtime though, you may still need to query the current processor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do [like @kobrien said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39670813/2851815), or you could take a more civilised approach - the [`cpuid` crate](https://crates.io/crates/cpuid).

To do that, add it to your `Cargo.toml` and then, to check for availability of the POPCNT do

```
extern crate cpuid;

fn have_popcnt() -> Option<bool> {
    cpuid::identify().ok().map(|ci| ci.has_feature(cpuid::CpuFeature::POPCNT))
}
```

The `have_popcnt()` function will return `None` if the CPU doesn't support the CPUID instruction or `Some(hp)`, where `hp` determines POPCNT's availability thereon.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the cpuid instruction. Check bit 23 of ecx.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID

Comment: There are crates for this, such as my own [cupid](https://crates.io/crates/cupid).